# IE6: jQuery pngfix + mouseover-events

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, hover, pngfix

i want to change the src-attrib of an img-element (png) when the cursor hits the element.
it works fine in all browser except the IE6 :(

at first the script does a pngfix() via jQuery PNGfix. So it wraps the img-element with a span-tag and drops the src-content through a filter into the span-tag.

my idea is, to get the style/css/... from the runtime-span element an replace this - instead of replacing the src-attrib of the img-tag. here is a snippet of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').bind
({
    mouseover : function() 
    {
        symbiontStatus = 1;
        $('img').css('backgroundImage', 'img/img02.png');
//...
```

In the pngfix script i've added a class to the span, so i can call it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pngfix').bind
    ({
        mouseover : function() 
        {
alert('over!');
            symbiontStatus = 1;
            $('.pngfix').css('backgroundImage', 'img/img02.png');
    //...
```

i have no idea to get the img02 into the pngfix as background. you? maybe?

thank you,
mario

Answer (score 0):

You could set the image `src` attribute and then again call `pngfix` on it. Before doing this you should remove the `span` added by the plugin after the `img` tag because `pngfix` will again create a span. Now that we will remove the `span` on which you have bound `mouseover`/`mouseout` events we will have to `live`. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pngfix').live('mouseover', function(){
            symbiontStatus = 1;
            var $img = $(this).prev();
            $(this).remove()

            $img.attr('src', 'img/img02.png').pngfix();
    //...
     });
});
```

Comment: http://jupiterjs.com/news/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live (just a nice article.)